# Magento: placing block on custom template

Tags: magento

We are creating a custom page in which we are making something of a product wizard and the final step, we want to pull in the product page, really the `catalog/product_view` block. Obviously we can create the block and set it in the page with the `renderview` method but the problem we are having is its only that block and none of its children, and since the `view.phtml` pulls in a ton of `getChildHtml` blocks nothing works.

I am thinking there has to be a way to place the product view block with all of its children in a custom non product page. Without having to create every single child block and their child blocks, is there a way to programmatically pull in all the blocks that are in an xml file like the `catalog_product_view` handle in `catalog.xml` and place it on another page?

The page we are trying to put it on is a category page using a custom template where we are doing a lot of PHP in the template file to do the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
//save the product in the registry so the block knows which product to display
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
Mage::register('product', $product);

//get the block from the layout and render it to html
$Block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$product_view = $Block->createBlock('catalog/product_view');
$product_view->setTemplate('catalog/product/view.phtml');
$product_view->toHtml();
```

I've had partial success with this code (part of the product view block is displayed and then  I get an error). Hopefully it will point you in the right direction.